# Show that any vertex cover, $K$, of a $k$-regular graph, $G$, satisfies $|K|\geq \frac{e(G)}{k}$.

Tags: graph-theory

Show that any vertex cover, $K$, of a $k$-regular graph satisfies $|K|\geq \frac{e(G)}{k}$.

So we have that the number of edges in a $k$-regular graph are $e(G)=\frac{k|G|}{2}$, then this rearranges to $\frac{e(G)}{k}=\frac{|G|}{2}$. This problem seem rather simple but my brain ceases to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$k|V| = 2e(G)$ as you righly notice (all edges are counted twice when we count every vertex times degree $k$ in that vertex).

But $K$ is a vertex cover, which means a set of vertices such that every edge of $G$ touches at least one of them. So we get a similar counting argument: for every $v \in K$ there are $k$ many edges connecting to it. So for members of $K$ we have in total $kK$. But this should be at least be $e(G)$ to obey the cover condition (every edge is at least one of these $kK$ many).

$$Kk \ge e(G)$$ which is what you need.

Comment: thank you so much! I feel like such a dunce.